# GCP Cloud Console - how to make sidebar fully scrollable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently only half of my sidebar is scrollable - only the items below "MORE PRODUCTS". How to make it fully scrollable, so everything above "MORE PRODUCTS" also scrolls with the rest of the sidebar?

I know it's possible because it's default behaviour for new accounts.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed anything in your account settings? I think new users don't have anything pinned to navigation sidebar, that's why it's fully scrollable. If you pin enough stuff to this navigation bar, you will get the behaviour that you desire.

Comment: @mdobrucki Thank you very much, this is the solution - to pin more items :). If you pin at least 6 items (on my screen at least) whole menu can be scrolled. Write it as an answer so I can select it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pin more items to the navigation sidebar (at least 6). It's not default behaviour.